# Automating Trajectory Processing in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, geoprocessing, trajectory

I'm currently working on a project where I'm processing a year's worth of Sentinel-6 data as it passes over different locations. I've been able to automate much of the process, but I haven't been able to figure out how to automate the AddDataToTrajectoryDataset part of the process. Here's the sample code:

```
arcpy.management.AddDataToTrajectoryDataset(in_trajectory_dataset, trajectory_type, input_path, {filter}, {sub_folder}, {aux_inputs})
```

I've had some success in that the tool runs but it doesn't populate the attribute table with the selected variables. These all run but don't produce the desired results:

```
ProductFilter = 'Standard'
Frequency = '1_Hz_Ku'
Variables = 'altitude;geoid;model_dry_tropo_cor_altitude;model_wet_tropo_cor_altitude;range_ocog'

arcpy.management.AddDataToTrajectoryDataset('Apr21_20HzKu', 'Sentinel-6', r'C:\Users\smith\OneDrive\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\GreatBearNTC\GreatBearNTC.gdb\Apr21_20HzKu', '*S6*', 'SUBFOLDERS', 'ProductFilter;Frequency;Variables')
```

and

```
arcpy.management.AddDataToTrajectoryDataset('Apr12_20HzKu', 'Sentinel-6', r'C:\Users\smith\OneDrive\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\GreatBearNTC\GreatBearNTC.gdb\Apr12_20HzKu', '', 'NO_SUBFOLDERS', aux_inputs='ProductFilter = "Standard"; Frequency = "20HzKu"; Variables = "altitude,geoid,model_dry_tropo_cor_altitude,model_wet_tropo_cor_altitude,range_ocog"')
```

I've tried a few variations of this and it all runs successfully. The arcpy window will even say that I have results and no errors. This is the most time-consuming part of the process and it would be nice if I could automate it. I think the issue comes from the aux_inputs section, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Does anyone have any suggestions?